# Find Subscriber By Id Marketing Cloud REST API from Event Notification data

Tags: marketing-cloud, event-notification-service

I am attempting to do what I feel is a very simple and common task but failing to complete it at every turn. The overview is to receive Marketing Cloud click, open and unsubscribe events, record them and take appropriate actions in our custom application.

I have successfully completed the registration and subscription of our [Event Notification Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/ens-get-started.htm?search_text=event%20notification). We are receiving [notification events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/ens-supported-events.htm?search_text=event%20notification) regularly (EngagementEvents). Perfect! Most of the EmailOpen events received look like this:

```
{
    "eventCategoryType": "EngagementEvents.EmailOpen",
    "timestampUTC": 1603307068000,
    "compositeId": "37263899.2167179.0.2519909999",
    "definitionKey": "NA",
    "definitionId": "NA",
    "channel": "email",
    "mid": 1500,
    "eid": 1500,
    "composite": {
        "jobId": "37263899",
        "batchId": "0",
        "listId": "2167179",
        "subscriberId": "2519909999"
    },
    "info": {
        "ipAddress": "8.8.8.8",
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148",
        "location": {
            "country": "US",
            "region": "VA",
            "city": "ASHBURN",
            "postalCode": "20146-20149",
            "latitude": "39.0438",
            "longitude": "-77.4879"
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand it, the "composite" object is the most important part to determine the email address that the opened email was sent to.

```
    "composite": {
        "jobId": "37263899",
        "batchId": "0",
        "listId": "2167179",
        "subscriberId": "2519909999"
    }
```

I am at a loss as to reliably find the email address of the user who opened this email which generated this event. I'm working with the [REST API v1 Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm).

I have been able to fetch a few subscribers using this REST call:

**URL**: {{rest_instance_url}}/contacts/v1/contacts/search
**BODY**:

```
{
    "request": {
        "attributes": {
            "key": "Contact.Contact Key"
        }
    },
    "conditionSet": {
        "operator": "Or",
        "conditionSets": [],
        "conditions": [
            {
                "attribute": {
                    "key": "Contact.Contact ID"
                },
                "operator": "Equals",
                "value": {
                    "items": [
                        "259352466"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "sort": "Contact.Contact ID"
}
```

I thought that would do it but it is only returning records with email addresses less than 5% of the time when I pass in a subscriberId from the Event notification EmailOpen payload.

When I invoke the REST API call **{{rest_instance_url}}/contacts/v1/contacts/search** with an empty body, it returns all results unfiltered and paged. The results look like this ...

```
{
    "page": 102,
    "pageSize": 2000,
    "count": 2000,
    "items": [
        {
            "contactKey": "fake@yahoo.com",
            "contactID": 259380986
        },
        {
            "contactKey": "invalid@earthlink.net",
            "contactID": 437892367
        },
    ...
    ]
}
```

If I plug one of those contactIDs back into the search above, it fails to find a record a significant number of times.

I am unable to locate good documentation on how to correlate this data. I am also unable to find good documentation on how to construct a search using the REST API to properly locate this data.

**My question is:**
It appears that if an email is opened, Marketing Cloud knows who opened it. How can I use the REST API to get the recipients email address from the event notification data provided?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The most reliable way of getting the email address would be by accessing the all subscribers list. Lists are only accessable by SOAP API. I also want to advise you that the email address should not be used as a Contact Key or Subscriber Key in Marketing Cloud. This is a really bad practice.

Comment: Thank you! I'm implementing this for a client who is managing the Marketing Cloud account. I will advise them of your suggestion. I will investigate the SOAP API for accessing the subscribers list. Do you have any resources other than the MC Documentation (out of date, has non-working code)? I have referenced this https://api.mcexperts.ninja/?version=latest#24cceab3-7921-4914-a08c-84ee99cbcc17 but keep getting a 400 Bad Request with the sample code (subbing in known working variables and values, of course). I'm at a loss on this.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Okay.. I see you get the SubscriberID and the List ID. This request here should get you the email address: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_subscribers_using_listid.htm I know its sf doc. most of the times the documentation is only missing the client id, which you need in an enterprise 2.0 setup. <ClientId>{{BusinessUnitId}}</ClientId> should be part of <RetrieveRequest>